# Simple NHibernate subquery - pulling my hair out

Tags: c#, nhibernate

All I want to do is lookup a value and return it in a subquery

```
select 
(select top 1 c.Type from ChangeTypes c where c.TypeID = r.ChangeType) as ChangeType,
COUNT(r.requestId) as RequestCount
from Request r 
group by ChangeType
```

I can't get this to work for the life of me...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You gave us SQL, not HQL but tagged it "NHibernate." If you want help debugging a problem using NHibernate, you should start by giving us what you already have.

Comment: If you're using NHibernate.Linq from 2.1 (pre 3.0) the LINQ provider doesn't support subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to

```
select
    (select c.Type
     from ChangeTypes c
     where c.Type.Id = r.ChangeType.Id) as rtypes,
    count(r.Requests) as rcount
from Request r
group by rtypes
```